Connectivity of intersection graph
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $N$ finite subsets of $S=\{1, \dots, N\}$, each of size $k$ and $\bigcup \mathcal{F} = S$, and let $G=(\mathcal{F}, E)$ be the intersection graph of $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e. $\{S_1, S_2\} \in E$ if and only if $S_1 \cap S_2 \neq \emptyset$.
Is there a necessary and suffice condition on $\mathcal{F}$ that will guarantee that $G$ is connected?

If, given a graph, you take for $\mathcal{F}$ the sets composed of incident edges for each vertex, then the graph is its incidence graph. Therefore any graph is an incidence graph, so you will not have a simpler characterisation of connectedness than for graphs.

@caduk I agree, but don't you have a little bit more information? You also know that you can interpret the graph as a line graph of say $G$ on $n$ vertices s.t. $G$ has precisely $n$ edges. Such a graph should be connected if and only if it is a $n$-vertex tree plus one edge. But maybe I'm confusing different things here

Adding to my previous answer: if $k=2$, then we can interpret $G$ as the line graph of a $N$-vertex graph $G'$, such that all vertices are covered and $G'$ has precisely $N$ edges. Since there are no isolated vertices in $G'$ it should be connected if and only if $G$ is connected. $G'$ is connected if and only if it is a spanning tree plus one more edge. This is equivalent to $G'$ being an $N$-vertex graph with no isolated vertices and exactly one cycle, I think.

Translating this back to our original setting in the case $k=2$ means that $G$ is connected if and only if there is exactly one choice of subsets $S_1,\ldots,S_m$ such that $S_1\cap S_2, S_2\cap S_3,\ldots, S_{m-1}\cap S_{m}, S_m \cap S_1$ are all non empty. But maybe I made a mistake in one of the steps. In the case that all this is correct, then maybe it is possible to generalize this reasoning to $k\ge 3$ somehow, but then we're dealing with k-uniform hypergraphs.
